# Vectors and Matrices from the NumPy Module

Tags: python, numpy

In python, how to write program that create two 4 * 4 matrices A and B whose elements are random numbers. Then create a matrix C that looks like

```
C = ⎡A B⎤
    ⎣B A⎦
```

Find the diagonal of the matrix C. The diagonal elements are to be presented in a 4 * 2 matrix.

```
import numpy as np

matrix_A = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 4))
matrix_B = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 4))

matrix_C = np.array([[matrix_A, matrix_B], [matrix_B, matrix_A]])
d= matrix_C.diagonal()
D=d.reshape(2,4)
print(f'This is matrix C:\n{matrix_C}')
print(f'These are the diagonals of Matrix C:\n{D}')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction

```
matrix_C = np.array([[matrix_A, matrix_B], [matrix_B, matrix_A]])
```

does not concatenate matrices, but creates 4th order tensor (put matrices inside matrix). You can check that by

```
print(matrix_C.shape)  # (2, 2, 4, 4)
```

To lay out blocks call  [`np.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html), then all other parts of your code should work fine:

```
matrix_C = np.block([[matrix_A, matrix_B], [matrix_B, matrix_A]])
print(matrix_C.shape)  # (8, 8)
d= matrix_C.diagonal()
D=d.reshape(2,4)  # np.array([matrix_A.diagonal(), matrix_A.diagonal()])
```